# Aysnc v3.1.0 => queue.push does nothing after no. of tasks are complete(defined concurrency)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, async-await, async.js

```
var que = async.queue(async function({id}) {   
  const res = await fetchData(id);
  return res;
}, 2);

que.push({id}, function (err, res) {
console.log('handle res');
});
```

Here concurrency is set as 2. so after first two tasks are done and if I push a new task in the queue. nothing happens. No err, even the task in also not pushed.

If I update concurrency to 5, it will perform the first 5 tasks and then it fails for the 6th task.

Do we have to clear the queue after each task is done?

I am using it in Reactjs project.

NOTE: I am able to make this work correctly on my local, but when I create the react build and deploy it, it does not work there.

Comment: sorry misunderstood the question, the codeblock is fine. Maybe, the problem is where you are pushing the async functions.

Comment: My que is a global object of a file and the file has a function when called push an async task into the queue.

Comment: I am able to make this work correctly on my local.. but when i create the react build and deploy it, it does not work there.